# Spring doesn't resolve #{systemEnvironment['NAME']} in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-el, spring-cloud-config

When I specify a plain absolute path in the `application.yml` everything works, but when I try to replace the project home directory with a value of environment variable, it's not working.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
      server:
        native:
#          searchLocations: file:#{systemEnvironment['PROJECT_HOME']}/backend/cloud-config/{application}
          searchLocations: file:/temp/pets/backend/cloud-config/{application}
```

In runtime the unresolved value (`file:#{systemEnvironment['PROJECT_HOME']}/backend/cloud-config/some-service`) is passed into `org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NativeEnvironmentRepository#getLocations`, and

```
if (isDirectory(value)) {
    output.add(value);
}
```

obviously `isDirectory(value)` returns false and eventually Spring's `spring.config.location=` is empty.

PS:
Used: `spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.2.RELEASE`

Stack trace:

```
2018-10-12 11:02:27.221  INFO 10392 --- [           main] t.m.c.ConfigServerApplication            : Started ConfigServerApplication in 4.058 seconds (JVM running for 4.67)
2018-10-12 11:02:27.437 ERROR 10392 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --spring.config.location=
    at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.parse(SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java:75) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.<init>(SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.java:87) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments$Source.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:76) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:42) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NativeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:110) [spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ConfigServerHealthIndicator.java:51) [spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:38) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint.invoke(HealthEndpoint.java:81) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint.invoke(HealthEndpoint.java:35) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.DataEndpointMBean.getData(DataEndpointMBean.java:48) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1252) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1246) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.SpringModelMBean.invoke(SpringModelMBean.java:90) [spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.getAttribute(RequiredModelMBean.java:1562) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.SpringModelMBean.getAttribute(SpringModelMBean.java:109) [spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1445) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:639) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

bash:

```
user@userspc:~$ printenv | grep PROJECT_HOME
PROJECT_HOME=/temp/pets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpEL is not supported in `application.yml`; you can, however, use property placeholders. Use `${PROJECT_HOME:unspecified}/...` (where `unspecified` will be used if the environment variable is not set.

Comment: you said "will be used if the environment variable is not set" but should I set it to be able to use inside `application.yml` or you meant java properties via `-D...`?

Comment: No; environment variables can populate properties; I tested with `$ export PROJECT_HOME=bar; ./mvnw spring-boot:run`; and `foo=${PROJECT_HOME:x}/foo` in the YML; the data after the `:` is used if the placeholder can't be resolved.